# Keep getting a seg fault when trying to open files with child and parent processes?

Tags: c, fork, fopen, fgets, pid

I am trying to open a text file and have both a child and parent process read from the file one line at a time and output their PID followed by the line that was read. Except no matter what I seem to do I keep getting a seg fault and can't even locate where my problem is.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    if(!argv[1]){
             return 1;
    }

    int var1 = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("prog2Boutput.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    int childP = fork();

    if(childP<0){
            fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    else if(childP==0){
            char* line = fgets(line,150, fp);
            printf("child: (pid:%d) (line:%s)\n", (int)getpid(), line);
    }
    else{
            char* line = fgets(line,150,fp);
            printf("parent: (pid:%d) (line:%s)\n", (int)getpid(), line);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `line` points to when you call `fgets`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have two errors:

1. You're using `strtol()` without checking that there's an `argv[1]`. You should put in a guard.
2. You aren't using `fgets()` correctly. The first argument must be a buffer that you allocate yourself, as in:

   ```
   char line[200];
   char *cp = fgets(line, 150, fp);
   ```

After that `cp` will be either 0 (when `fgets()` couldn't read anything) or it will point to the first character of `line`.

(Last, as point of style, `main()` should return an `int`, not `void`. Some modern compilers won't accept your code.)